# How to find the upper bound of an integral given the area

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

I am trying to do some decent programming for once, and it looks like math is unavoidable. I got pretty far with no math background, but now I'm stuck after days of trying to find an answer.

I have the following function, which I use to decelerate an object:

$$f(x)=3000\,\cdot\,0.135064522447^x\,\,\,.$$

As $x$ increases (time), the speed, which starts at $3000$, gets lower and lower.

I want to discover the distance traveled by the object, and for that I first determine when it will stop, meaning when $x$ is $10$ as zero may take forever. I substitute $x$ with $10$ and solve the equation, which means I found a tool that does it for me as my math skills are very poor.

$$\frac{\log\left(\frac{1}{\frac{3000}{10}}\right)}{\log(0.135064522447)}$$

$$p_3=2.84903839451$$

So now I know when the object stops. Using this information, I can calculate the total distance traveled by using an integral, and this resulting number as an upper bound: (here $f_{99}(t)$ is the first function mentioned, the $99$ represents my struggle with many attempts).

$$C=\int_0^{2.84903839451}f_{99}(t)\text{d}t$$

$$C=1493.50450117$$

All of this took me days... had to start learning math again... but it seems like this is where it ends.

I have one question left, how do I determine the upper bound of the integral (time in seconds) when the area is let's say 500? Which means, what's the time at which the object traveled 500 units?

Looking on the internet seems futile, I guess this is not a common thing to do? If you can please explain it for someone not too familiar with math, as I have to convert it to code. Feel free to suggest edits as I'm not even sure I'm using the correct wording, tags or title.

Comment: The speed will never become 0, but the distance is finite: $s=\frac{v_0}{a}$ where $a=-\log(0.135064522447) \approx 2.0020026706707346$, and the total distance is about $1498.5$.

Comment: Write $v(t) = v_0 e^{-\alpha t}$, then the distance traveled
starting at time $t_0$ and ending at $t_1$ is $x(t_1)-x(t_0) = \int_{t_0}^{t_1} v(x)dx = {v_0 \over \alpha}(e^{-\alpha t_0} - e^{-\alpha t_1})$. In your example, $v_0 = 3000$, $\alpha = -\ln (0.135...)$.

Answer (score 2):

If $f(x)=a\cdot b^x$ is the velocity at time $x$

then the distance travelled by time $t$ is $C(t) = \int\limits_0^t f(x)\, dx = a\dfrac{b^t-1}{\log_e(b)}$
and if $C(t)=k$ then $t= \dfrac{\log_e(\frac ka \log_e(b)+1)}{\log_e(b)}$

Here you have $a=3000$ and $b=0.135064522447$, so

- $C(10)\approx 1498.4994965$
- $\lim\limits_{t\to +\infty}C(t)\approx 1498.4994995$ which is not much more
- Solving $C(t)=500$ gives $t\approx 0.20278$

Comment: Incidentally, if you were originally aiming to have $\lim\limits_{t\to +\infty}C(t) =1500$ then you could do it with $a=3000$ and $b=e^{-2} \approx 0.1353352832$, which would make $C(t)=500$ give $t=\frac12\log_e(\frac32) \approx 0.20273$